# Not able to find UserControl on a master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have put a user control on my template page, say Test.aspx

```
 <site:Control1 runat="server" id="Bigbox" AdType="bigbox" AdTile="1" ServeOop="True"/>
```

And in the code behind of Control1, it is trying to find another user control that is put on the master page.

```
 if (this.Page.Master.FindControl("Control2") != null),
```

Now, the way we designed our sites is that we have template page calls a master page that calls another master page, what i meant is this

in Test.aspx, it has

```
MasterPageFile="~/Views/CMSTemplates/Shows/Show.master"
```

and in Show.master, it has

```
MasterPageFile="~/Views/CMSTemplates/Wrapper.master"
```

in Wrapper.master, it has `"~/Views/CMSTemplates/Site.master"`

Now, site.master is the master page at the root level, all templates make reference to that.

But when I put Control2 on the site.master

```
<site:Control2 runat="server" id="Control2"/>,
```

if (this.Page.Master.FindControl("Control2") returns null. I understand because Site.Master is several levels up from Test.aspx, so I tried putting Control2 at Show.master
Wrapper.master, Control1 still failed to find Control2.

I even tried to put the @masterType directive, still wouldn't work

Any ideas or suggestions?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the <@mastertype reference on the template page. And i used the Page.Master.Master to go up the chain and find the control

Answer (score 2):

You need to look for the control by ID, not class name:

```
if (this.Page.Master.FindControl("DfpAdManager") != null)
```

Or use `OfType`:

```
this.Page.Master.Controls.OfType<Control2>()
```

Comment: I am looking them up by ID.

Comment: No you aren't. "Control2" is not the ID. "DfpAdManager" is the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try inspecting or searching for controls from Page.Master.Parent, depending on where in the hierarchy you've put the control you're searching for, and where you are conducting the FindControl() from. 
You can go Page.Master.Parent.Parent. etc if need be.

Comment: essentially my master pages are nested. So I tried Page.Master.master...are you suggesting i should try Page.master.parent.parent instead?